# I would like to create a web and mobile app. What are the best technologies to start with?

Tags: android, ios, web-applications

I am new for this level of programming so please bare with me.

So I took a project, this is the most complex I have ever taken, so I need some help to point me to the right direction.

The goal of the webapp is to let users pay for their parking troght mobile app ( both for andrioid and IOS)

Little bit more detalis:

I need a website, on the backend this would handle all the necesarry logic, and API
on the frontend the clines can register new account and each account cen register new parking zones. Each zone has their own prices, and other attributes like time range ( how long user has to pay for the parking Example: from 6am to 8 pm, after 8 is free ) etc.

I need a UI where users can choose based on geolocation, witch parking zone they going to use, set the time period how long they wanna park at the given location.

This is it on a nutshell. Of course there are many more details, but I tink I can solve the rest.

So my main question is how to implement this web app on a way, that it will be scaleable and stable.

My opinion (Witch not necesarry correct) NodeJS and MongoDB would be the best pick for backend since i dont think I need SQL DB. I want to store every client account and every parkingzone. I dont want user account or to store any payment details ( however I would like the app to store it offline if it possible or store it via the payment gateway (Sorry if this q is dump, its my lack of knowledge.))

So my first tought was If each client account would get their own database So one database would only store the parkingzones on that city where the account been registered. ( Also it might be important deatil we only allow one account per city.)  I think it would make the requests ever faster, if i have lets say 100 client acc each with over 100 parking zones. But is it has a down side? if it does withc would be the best way for the databases?

After this is done I need an API what will communicate with the website ( admin and client accs) and the UI

On the UI site I want to make a crosspaltform moblie app, it shouldt be too difficult. All I need is:
User gives theri License Plate number
The time period when they wanna finish parking
And choose the parking zone based on theri geolocation.

So to implement this I think PWA would be a simple and fast solution, but if it has too many downside React Native might be a better way to do it.

Sorry if I took long with this post.

Comment: `What are the best technologies to start with?` i'm going to say do it using X, someone else is going to say do it using Y, we're all going to have different answers and opinions, there isn't a correct answer to your question here

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends upon your skills and timeline.

**For Web:**

If you already have skills with NodeJs/Express and MongoDB so you can easily create backend and apis for Web and Mobile App. If you don't have enough skills and you have less timeline so you can go with the firebase database, in that case no apis will be needed and everything will be server less. For web frontend you can use any either plain html/css/js or either React (If you want a scalable and fast Web App).

**For Mobile App:**

The best option is React Native for cross platform Mobile App. If you learn React then you can use it on both Web and Mobile App. React Native in addition has its own components for UI other than normal html tags.

So I will suggest either go with:

React, React Native, Firebase

or

React, React Native, NodeJS/Express and MongoDB

In case of React, business logic can be shared across Web and Mobile App, like same code for api request, same reducers, etc

Comment: Thanks, your answer was really helpful. So I drop the idea of PWS and go with React.
I dont have too much knowledge about JS or NodeJS, neither React but I got 2 months to get this skills. Many thanks!

Comment: You can also generate PWA of React Web App

Comment: In that case can I store the payment details somewhere else other then on my server?

Comment: See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments